# SQL Query - How to output duplicate values

Tags: sql, sql-server

I've got a very simple COUNT query to show where a user has duplicate records in a table.

```
SELECT      [name], COUNT([name])
FROM        [user]
GROUP BY    [name]
HAVING      COUNT([name]) > 1
ORDER BY    COUNT([name])
```

This outputs something like the below:

```
Name       | Count
---------------------
Mr Smith   | 3
Mr Foster  | 3
Mr Johnson | 4
```

I'd like to then output each row that is found with another field from the table ([reference]) like the below:

```
Name       | Reference
---------------------
Mr Smith   | REF-1
Mr Smith   | REF-2
Mr Smith   | REF-3
Mr Foster  | REF-4
Mr Foster  | REF-5
Mr Foster  | REF-6
Mr Johnson | REF-7
Mr Johnson | REF-8
Mr Johnson | REF-9
Mr Johnson | REF-10
```

What's the best way to do this? Apologies if it's very simple - I just can't get my head around it! Thanks in advance.

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: Hi jarlh - I'm using Microsoft SQL Server. Thanks

Comment: @RyanJackson - It appears that your current output vs your expected output are in direct conflict of each other. Your original output does the grouping with COUNT as expected but then your anticipated output breaks them out into their own rows again. 

Based on your expected output it sounds like you simply want to use the ROW_NUMBER function concatenated against this other reference column.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `row_number()`:

```
SELECT name, reference,
       CONCAT('Ref-', ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY cnt, name) as ref
FROM (SELECT u.*,
             COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY name) as cnt
      FROM [user] u
     ) u
WHERE cnt > 1
ORDER BY cnt, name;
```

Comment: Hi Gordon, apologies I've just edited the question slightly.

I'd like to then output each row that is found with another field from the table - [reference]

Comment: @RyanJackson . . . Just select it in the outer query.  The key then is the window function for doing the count.